# Iterate through ImageViews and set random drawable and visibility

Tags: android, random, imageview, visibility

I make a little game and have a problem iterating through ImageViews.

I have 12 ImageViews, which should show randomly no apple, a green or a red apple.

How can i iterate through ImageViews and set Visibility and drawable?
The App crashes: "App has stopped"

```
    void shuffleApples() {

    ImageView[] apples = new ImageView[12];
    apples[0] = img_apple1;
    apples[1] = img_apple2;
    apples[2] = img_apple3;
    apples[3] = img_apple4;
    apples[4] = img_apple5;
    apples[5] = img_apple6;
    apples[6] = img_apple7;
    apples[7] = img_apple8;
    apples[8] = img_apple9;
    apples[9] = img_apple10;
    apples[10] = img_apple11;
    apples[11] = img_apple12;

    for(int i = 0; i < apples.length; i++) {
        Random randomAppleVisibility = new Random();
        Random randomAppleColor = new Random();
        int appleVisibility = randomAppleVisibility.nextInt(0);
        int appleColor = randomAppleColor.nextInt(0);

        if(appleVisibility==0) {
            apples[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            if(appleColor==0) {
                apples[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.apple_red);
                redApples++;
            }
            else {
                apples[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.apple_green);
                greenApples++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to produce a random integer value of `0` or `1` do this:

```
int appleVisibility = randomAppleVisibility.nextInt(2);
int appleColor = randomAppleColor.nextInt(2);
```

This

```
nextInt(0)
```

throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` because the argument must be a positive number.  
About `nextInt()`:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

You should consider putting these lines:

```
Random randomAppleVisibility = new Random();
Random randomAppleColor = new Random();
```

before the `for` loop.